# Unity(Dependency Injection) in ASP.NET CORE like what we have in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

(This is my first post so far, please take it easy)
I recently work with Onion Architecture in ASP.NET Framework, everything is fine until my boss tells me that he wants a similar architecture in the new project, but use ASP.NET CORE this time.
Basically, ASP.NET CORE can perform the same behavior as the Framework, but I'm having a problem to force DI working as a service like what [Jeffrey Palermo](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) defined. The problem is ASP.NET CORE is already support embedded DI, it's nice, convenience, but now I completely want the totally different stupid thing. So, if any of you ever having the same situation, please share! Many thanks.

**[UPDATED_1]**
Thanks, @sellotape for your advice, I'll break it down a little bit more.
As I mentioned above, the architecture defined that every service (include DI) must act like nothing, but an onion layer. This means the DI itself must not depend on the framework (ASP.NET CORE built-in DI this time). 
That's all my problem about, it's just a picky idea to keep up with the architecture.

**[UPDATED_2]**
Let say my ASP.NET Framework project structure would look like this:

```
*Onion.sln                        --(project solution)
 - Core                           --(solution folder)
   + Core.ApplicationServices     --(project)
   + Core.ObjectModels            --(project)
   + Core.ObjectServices
 - Infrastructure
   + Infrastructure.Data
   + Infrastructure.Log
   + Infrastructure.Identity
 - Services
 - Libraries
 - DependencyResolver
```

As you can see, I am able to inject whatever I need to whatever project I want, thanks for DependencyResolver. This behavior seems not legal in ASP.NET CORE because to perform such things, you need the reference of a whole project to another, cause' the built-in DI container is "project-scope" only. This means, if I want to inject something from one to another, I create a tightly coupled between these two, and this is not what Dependency Injection live for.

Comment: There is nothing incompatible between Onion architecture and the DI available in .NET Core.  Perhaps you could explain a little further why Core's DI doesn't seem to meet your needs?  (Edit your question if SO allows you, to add more).

Comment: @sellotape, I have updated my question as you suggest. I googled up and someone said that it is able to use DI framework such as Unity and Ninject inside ASP.NET CORE. I'm digging up on research recently.

Comment: I still don’t really see the issue. If DI is done correctly, the only thing that knows about the DI specifics is where you configure the DI container. Everything else just uses (typically) constructor-injected interfaces which are completely DI-implementation agnostic. In the ASP.NET Core world, that means your Startup.cs knows about the DI and “fills” the container. Nothing else knows about it nor cares. With Ninject/StructureMap/etc. you get similar (and a bit more for edge cases) functionality, but nothing else changes. If I’m missing a point feel free to elaborate more.

Comment: @sellotape, sorry for not being clear, I have updated my question again. Hope this can help us to understand each other.

Comment: It's difficult to comment more usefully without seeing some working code.  I suppose it's proprietary, but perhaps you're able to strip out the basics and put it on GitHub?  Are you actually doing DI and not just service-location?  BTW I was randomly reading on another topic yesterday and came across something by Palermo referencing exactly this: Onion architecture on .NET Core.  It's light on detail though (at the very end): https://www.codemag.com/Article/1901041/A-Professional-Grade-Configuration-for-Azure-DevOps-Services-Beyond-the-Quickstarts

Comment: Thank you, @sellotape. I'll spend some time on it.